# Why does this code that uses .isalnum not work?

Tags: python

```
name = ""
name = input("Hi there, what is your name? ")
while name.isalnum():
   name = input("Hi there, what is your name? ")
while name.isdigit():
   name = input("Hi there, what is your name? ")
```

This is what the code looks like, but I only want it to accept letters only. When I run this code however, there is a problem and the program keeps asking for the user's name for any input provided, the only way the program continues is if a 'space (bar)' is pressed. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Why are there two loops?

Comment: As seen in the comments to an answer, you have not explained exactly what you want to accept and what to reject. You want to accept names that include only spaces and letters in the English/ASCII alphabet, I assume? What about apostrophe, as in O'Malley? And so on. Your question cannot be answered until you make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
while name.isalnum():
```

Means that the loop will **keep running** as long as name is alphanumeric. You want:

```
while not name.isalnum():
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work, but I want the program to NOT accept names that are alphanumerical, but even when I replace the 'while' with the 'while not', the code still does not work properly

Comment: @AbukarAwes: You've probably misunderstood the term "alphanumerical", unless you want to ensure that your program is only used by people with names like that weird thing Prince started calling himself. `isalnum` doesn't mean "contains both letters and numbers"; it means that each character in the string is alphanumerical (and there is at least one character).

Answer (score 0):

Your goal can be better achieved through `regex`:

```
import re
p=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z\s]+$')
name="user0000"
while not p.match(name):
    name = input("Hi there, what is your name? ")
```

This will accept names like "George Smith" but not "Smith1980"